# Sorted Iterable Efficient Sorted Structure in Java

Tags: java, collections, sorting

I've looked through (probably dozens) of StackOverflow questions, and I don't think I've found what I'm looking for.

I want a Java structure with the following properties:

1. Sorted
2. Iterable
3. Supports generics
4. O(logn) (or better) insertion and removal
5. O(logn) (or better) element access
6. Allows duplicate entries

Why?  I'm implementing a k-nearest distances algorithm.  For each point in a data collection, I need to find the distance to the kth nearest other point.  The algorithm works by iterating through each pair of points, calculating the distance between them, and then adding that distance to each point's sorted structure of nearest distances if the distance is closer than other elements in that list.  Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
ArrayList<SortedThing<Double>> nearestDistances = new ArrayList<SortedThing<Double>>(numPoints);
for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    nearestDistances.add(new SortedThing<Double>(k));
}

for (int point = 0; point < numPoints; point++) {
    for (int otherPoint = point+1; otherPoint < numPoints; otherPoint++) {
        double distance = computeDistance(point, otherPoint);

        if (nearestDistances.get(point).size < k)
            nearestDistances.get(point).add(distance);
        else if (nearestDistances.get(point).last() > distance) {
            nearestDistances.get(point).removeLast();
            nearestDistances.get(point).add(distance);
        }

        if (nearestDistances.get(otherPoint).size < k)
            nearestDistances.get(otherPoint).add(distance);
        else if (nearestDistances.get(otherPoint).last() > distance) {
            nearestDistances.get(otherPoint).removeLast();
            nearestDistances.get(otherPoint).add(distance);
        }
    }
}
```

Before you suggestion any of the following built-in Java classes, here's why I don't want to use them:

1. PriorityQueue - can't access the last element in it
2. TreeSet - won't allow duplicate distances
3. ArrayList - yes, I could use an ArrayList, insert all n-1 distances into it,sort it in O(nlogn) time, and then remove the kth element.  However, this would require O(n^2) space instead of O(nk) space.
4. ArrayList - alternatively, I could maintain a sorted ArrayList, removing the last element and inserting new elements into it in the correct position, but the insert will take O(k) time for each insert, and O(logk) to find the position for the insert.

Does anyone know of such a structure?  I've been thinking about this a lot lately, and it boggles me that Java doesn't provide any such structure.

Comment: Just for the record, TreeSet *would* be ideal if it allowed duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing nearest-neighbor search, then you might want to use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree); [here's a Java implementation](http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/software/kd/) (look in the \bak directory in the .jar file for the source code)

Otherwise, I'd suggest using a TreeMap, where the value is the number of key duplicates (1 means no duplicates, 2 means one duplicate, etc)

```
Map<Key, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

if(map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
} else {
    map.put(key, 1);
}
```

Comment: Bingo!  I don't know how I didn't think of this.  Thank you very much!

One other point, in regards to the k-d tree:
I don't want to use any type of index structure (such as a k-d tree) for sorting the points, as I am going to need to do the k-nearest distances search many times on many different combinations of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Check [TreeBag](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/TreeBag.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

`TreeBag` uses `TreeMap` to hold the entries.

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but I think I'm going to stick with the TreeMap implementation suggested by Zim-Zam, as it is less work to deal with.

Comment: It's conceptually the same as `TreeBag` uses `TreeMap` internally.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  It's just easier to use TreeMap, since I don't need to download anything (what I meant by "less work").